# Regex to remove prefix and suffix in a string Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove prefix and suffix in a String and extract the middle portion of the string.

For eg: Consider the Strings - **"www.hello.com"** and **"www.test.com"**

Here **prefix - "www."** and **suffix - ".com"**. I want to extract the middle words - **hello** and **test**.

Currently i have achieved this using String.replace() method in Java.
str.replace("www.","").replace(".com","");

I want know is there any regular expression available to achieve it in a single method in java.

Comment: What you are doing is right!

Comment: You *can* use a regular expression for this, but you really shouldn’t.  In fact, you make sure you don’t get false positives from a hostname like `www.cdn.company.com`, you would be better off doing `str.substring(4, str.length() - 4)`.

Comment: Is your string always in form `www.abc.com` or can it contain also other text? If it contains only URL then `substring` may be simpler approach like shown in @VGR comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex for that, it would work in the same way. Your regex would simply contain a capture group with both the prefix and the suffix in an OR operation.

```
(www\.|\.com)
```

You could then use this like you did with the replace.

```
String test = "www.test.com";
String output = test.replaceAll("(www\\.|\\.com)","")
```

**P.S.** this code is untested. Please don't just copy and paste it expecting everything to work.

Answer (score 2):

(?<=www.)(.*)(?=.com)

This uses the lookbehind and lookahead feature of regex